# is it possible to load a picture in an alert box?

Tags: javascript

I am trying to have a picture to load onclick into an alert box but I am getting 
`"[object HTMLImageElement]"` where the picture should be.

This is what I have:

```
 function joePic(){
 var joe_fat = new Image;
 joe_fat.src = "pic1.jpg";
 alert (joe_fat);
 }

 <input type="button" value="Click here it find out" name="joePhoto" onclick="joePic()" 
 height="150" width="150" />
```

Is this possible?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

No, you can only put plain text (and linebreaks/carriage returns) into an alert box. If you need 'fancy' popups, you'll have to simulate them with a floating overlay on your page.

Comment: http://jqueryui.com/demos/dialog/ has nice, themeable dialogs if you are looking for an alternative to alerts.

Answer (score 1):

probably your best bet for this is to use [dialog](http://jqueryui.com/demos/dialog/) in jquery ui or use one of the separate plugins like [colorbox for jquery](http://jacklmoore.com/colorbox/).

Could also [look through here](http://www.designlabelblog.com/2009/03/20-ways-to-create-javascript-modal.html) to see if you can find something suitable